# Debian install TP-LINK TL-WN723N Wireless usb

Tags: linux, debian, driver, wireless

i'm downloading rtl8188eu-master file from github for install this driver on debian. after extract it and run make command in get this error.

```
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.11-2-486/build M=/home/tux-world/Desktop/Home/rtl8188eu-master  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11-2-486'
  CC [M]  /home/tux-world/Desktop/Home/rtl8188eu-master/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/tux-world/Desktop/Home/rtl8188eu-master/core/rtw_cmd.c:23:0:
/home/tux-world/Desktop/Home/rtl8188eu-master/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/tux-world/Desktop/Home/rtl8188eu-master/include/osdep_service.h:1406:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘daemonize’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  daemonize("%s", name);
  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[4]: *** [/home/tux-world/Desktop/Home/rtl8188eu-master/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/tux-world/Desktop/Home/rtl8188eu-master] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11-2-486'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

`linux-headers-3.11-2-486` and `build-essential` packages are installed and i do not have problem for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this has little to do with programming, I will answer this in case somebody comes here with a similar issue.

I had no trouble compiling the driver with these commands (make sure you have the headers installed):

```
wget https://codeload.github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/zip/master
unzip master
cd rtl8188eu-master
sudo make
sudo make install
```